# How to "de-sugar" this Scala statement?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, json4s

LINQ-style queries in Scala with `json4s` look as follows:

```
val jvalue = parse(text) // (1)
val jobject = for(JObject(o) <- jvalue) yield o // (2)
```

I do not understand exactly how (2) works. How would you de-sugar this `for`-statement ?

Comment: Be aware that filter on a JValue traverses the full JSON tree. So you are not just matching the `jvalue`, but all nodes below too. In other words it does a search on the JSON tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for-comprehensions of the form

```
for(v <- generator) yield expr
```

are translated into

```
generator.map(v => expr)
```

When you have a pattern match on the left, then any input values which do not match the pattern are filtered out. This means a partial function is created containing the match, and each input argument can be tested with `isDefinedAt` e.g.

```
val f: PartialFunction[JValue, JObject] = { case o@JObject(_) => o }
f.isDefinedAt(JObject(List[JField]()))   //true
f.isDefinedAt(JNull)                     //false
```

This means your example will be translated into something like:

```
PartialFunction[JValue, List[JField]] mfun = { case JObject(o) -> o }
var jobject = jvalue.filter(mfun.isDefinedAt(_)).map(mfun)
```